# window.webkitAudioContext not working on Safari

Tags: audio, safari, web-audio-api, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I'm trying to use the Audio API on Safari to get the audio from the mic.

I don't understand why but webkitAudioContext is not working on Safari (I'm running on Safari 12.0.x, so it should be supported). It's working fine on Firefox since I'm using the window.AudioContext.

```
let MyAudioCtx = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let audioContext = new MyAudioCtx();
```

This code returns this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext`

Do you have any idea why? What can I do to solve this?